# Block from controller in magento

Tags: magento, block

I'm trying to display content in /index.php/pincel/payment/error/ and I have the next files:

Block/Error.php

`<?php
class PincelStudios_Pincel_Block_Error extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
?>`

etc/config.xml

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <pincel>
                <file>pincel.xml</file>
            </pincel>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Controller/PaymentController.php

```
    public function errorAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}
```

But I'm getting a white layout without any error (neither in logs)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzLkk.png

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a template file (.phtml), what is the content of pincel.xml?

Comment: did you set a route for pincel?

Comment: Hello, Yes, on my config.xml I have this:
        `<routers>
            <pincel>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>PincelStudios_Pincel</module>
                    <frontName>pincel</frontName>
                </args>
            </pincel>
        </routers>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have not given all necessary information and the file

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/pincel.xml
```

is missing.

```
<pincel_payment_error>
    <reference name="content"> <!-- Place were you want to display your content -->
        <block type="pincel/error" name="pincel" template="yourtemplate if necessary" />
    </reference>
</pincel_payment_error>
```

Do you have it?

Comment: +1 
renderLayout() will load the pincel_payment_error handle in your layout. You have to make sure it's clearly defined.

Comment: Yes, I added the file and still empty. Is there any way to add the content directly from controller? (there are just a few static textlines).

Comment: In this case you can create Static Block in Magento Admin and use in controller this: $this->loadLayout(); $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId("YOURBLOCKNAME"));  $this->renderLayout();